# Help creating a test class for automating contact creation

Tags: unit-test, class, contact, user

I'm very new to Salesforce, Apex, and programming in general.

I'm having trouble creating a test class for my class and trigger.  I've looked through similar questions, but they all seem to be far more complicated than mine.  The class and trigger are supposed to create a Contact whenever a User is created, and automatically populate some of the fields.

The code is in it's early stages, but I want to test it before going any further because this is the first time I've been without any "problems" in the log.

Here is the CLASS

```
public class UserContact {
    @future public static void createUserContact(set<ID> recordIDs){
        list<user> users = [SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname, email, name
                            FROM user
                            WHERE ID in :recordIDs];
        for (user x: users){
            account AccountX = [SELECT ID
                                FROM account];
            Contact userCon = new contact(
            AccountID = AccountX.id,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            email = x.Email);
            insert userCon;
            usercon.account.Name = 'Company Internal';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the TRIGGER

```
trigger NewUserCreatedTrigger on User (after insert) {
    user[] users = trigger.new;
    UserContact.createUserContact(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Here is the TEST CLASS I attempted to create

```
@isTest private class UserContactTest {
    testmethod static void userCreationTest(){
        User u = UserContact.createUserContact(User.id);
        u.Firstname = 'mike';
        u.LastName = 'Smith';
        u.email = 'msmith@company.com';
        insert u;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into in the test class, is it's asking for a variable from createUserContact and I'm not sure what to use because I'm referencing ID's.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I recommend you go to trailhead and go through the Test Class module there. Once you do, things will be much more obvious as to what you need to do. In essence, you need to create data that your trigger uses, then insert a record that causes your trigger to fire.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing that right now.  However, the modules seem to use hard coded data, such as "test that 90 is the same as the variable 'celsius'"

I'm trying to see if, when I create a user, it creates a contact automatically.  However, the console gives me the error that I don't have the correct parameters for 'createUserContact'

I am continuing the modules, but I was hoping for some clarification on this specific scenario.

Comment: Yes, test classes create test data that you generate programmatically. The ID's are generated on the fly as they're inserted. You'll need to specify a profile for the user you're creating along with an alias and other required fields (depends on type of user). See the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) for more on what those are.